# Database not being updated after commit()

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I have a method that persists lots of rows on the database, it's something like this:

```
private EntityManager em;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Map props = new HashMap();
    props.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JTA_DATASOURCE, dataSource());
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("db1", props);
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
}

public void persistAll(List list) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Object o : list) {

        if (count == 0) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
        }
        em.persist(o);

        count++;
        if (count >= 500) {
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

And here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="db1" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>db1</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <class>com.entities.entity1</class>
        <class>com.entities.entity2</class>
        <class>com.entities.entity3</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The transaction is opened at the beginning and committed after persisting 500 objects, then the transaction is opened again, and so on. This process will repeat until all the objects are persisted.

The problem is that the objects are only being saved on the database after the whole list is processed, if I interrupt the execution, even if the transaction has already been committed, it doesn't save anything.

Does anyone have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Should work. I have tested your code and see the records in the DB after each commit....

Comment: that's what the log is for, no?

Comment: @AlanHay I just updated the post with the persistence.xml code and the entityManager inicialization.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of commit, invoke the flush(); do somethign like

```
// open the transaction
// start the loop
// for each 500 call entityManager.flush();
// when the loop finishes, call commit() and finish the entityManagfer
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Sometimes people has no courage to tell why the answer is not good... -_-''

Comment: Commit will write any unflushed changes so making an explicit call to flush() will not make any difference: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html#commit()

Comment: Note that he was only opening one and calling commit several times.

Comment: @uaiHebert Actually I call begin() again every time I commit.